# Windows 10 is telling me incorrect info about remaining space left on RAM disk

Tags: windows, disk-space, ramdisk

### Problem

In the image below you can see that my RAMDisk, Drive Z, is out of space.

But if you look at the second image showing the contents of the RAMDisk it doesn't show that its taking up the space. Why is Windows calculating the free space incorrectly.

I have already emptied the recycling bin.

## Images

Figure1:
[image: out of space on RAM Disk]

Figure2:
[image: plenty of space left]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, there are still files in the RAMDisk that aren't linked into any directory, so you can't see them by looking at the folders.

As is the case with most modern filesystems, NTFS controls when files are deleted internally. You cannot tell it to delete a file, only to remove a file from a directory. If a file is in no directories, it can be deleted when it is no longer open in any process. But while it's still open, it will not be deleted.

You can use tools like [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what process(es) have files open on the drive. Search all handles for `Z:`.

You might also want to use a tool like [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) just in case there are files that you can't see.

Comment: There's a potential that your user rights don't allow you to see the contents of the SysVol folder, so it probably wouldn't bring up the storage allocation for it.  Why that folder would take up that much space is a totally different question.